Why two successive transactions throws lazyloadingexception?
Banging my head on this one...
I've a piece of code like this which wraps JPA Entities into vertices and which wraps JPA Relationships into Edges :
public GraphTraversalSource modelGraphFromMetamodelGraph(org.jgrapht.Graph<MetamodelVertex, FieldEdge<MetamodelVertex>> entityMetamodelGraph) {
    log.info("Creating model vertex");
    GraphTraversalSource gTS = this.graphTraversalSource.getGraph();
    TransactionTemplate tpl = new TransactionTemplate(sourcePlatformTxManager);
    tpl.setReadOnly(true);
    tpl.executeWithoutResult(status -> {
        createVertices(entityMetamodelGraph, gTS);
        createEdges(entityMetamodelGraph, gTS);
    });
    return gTS;
}

That works totally fine.
Unfortunately this code throws OOM on big databases thus I'm trying to 'Stream' it and make Transactions/Sessions more atomic.
But unfortunately, when I'm modifying this piece of code like this:
public GraphTraversalSource modelGraphFromMetamodelGraph(org.jgrapht.Graph<MetamodelVertex, FieldEdge<MetamodelVertex>> entityMetamodelGraph) {
    log.info("Creating model vertex");
    GraphTraversalSource gTS = this.graphTraversalSource.getGraph();
    createVertices(entityMetamodelGraph, gTS);
    createEdges(entityMetamodelGraph, gTS);
    return gTS;
}

private void createVertices(Graph<MetamodelVertex, FieldEdge<MetamodelVertex>> entityMetamodelGraph, GraphTraversalSource graphTraversalSource) {
    log.info("Creating model Vertex");
    TransactionTemplate tpl = new TransactionTemplate(sourcePlatformTxManager);
    tpl.setReadOnly(true);
    tpl.executeWithoutResult(status ->
        createVertices(entityMetamodelGraph.vertexSet(), graphTraversalSource);
    );
}

void createEdges(Graph<MetamodelVertex, FieldEdge<MetamodelVertex>> entityMetamodelGraph, GraphTraversalSource graphTraversalSource) {
    log.info("Creating model edges");
    TransactionTemplate tpl = new TransactionTemplate(sourcePlatformTxManager);
    tpl.setReadOnly(true);
    tpl.executeWithoutResult(status ->
        modelGraphEdgeBuilder.createEdges(graphTraversalSource, entityMetamodelGraph);
    );
}

I face a lovely
[ERROR] net.osgiliath.FakerProcessingIT.givenFedGraphWhenEntityProcessorAndSequenceProcessorIsCalledThenTargetDatabaseIsPopulatedExcludingCyclicPathAndFieldsAreTransformed -- Time elapsed: 0.079 s <<< ERROR!
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: net.osgiliath.datamigrator.sample.domain.JhiUser.jhiAuthorities: could not initialize proxy - no Session
        at org.hibernate.collection.spi.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:634)
        at org.hibernate.collection.spi.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:217)
        at org.hibernate.collection.spi.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:613)
        at org.hibernate.collection.spi.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:136)
        at org.hibernate.collection.spi.PersistentSet.iterator(PersistentSet.java:166)
        at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.estimateSize(Spliterators.java:1959)
        at java.base/java.util.Spliterator.getExactSizeIfKnown(Spliterator.java:414)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:508)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:596)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:276)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1708)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:596)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:276)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.Traversal.forEachRemaining(Traversal.java:278)
        at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1939)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.reduce(ReferencePipeline.java:667)
        at net.osgiliath.migrator.core.graph.TinkerpopModelGraphEdgeBuilder.createEdges(TinkerpopModelGraphEdgeBuilder.java:68)

Any idea of why this thing is happening? Any potential fix?
Thank you in advance
PS: the code is here if you want the complete picture: https://github.com/OsgiliathEnterprise/data-migrator/blob/main/core/src/main/java/net/osgiliath/migrator/core/graph/ModelGraphBuilder.java
To try to describe what this code is trying to achieve.
Let's say that we have a schema with two entities, A and B, with A containing a OneToMany relationship x to Bs.
First method
The call to createVertices will start a transaction which will select * from A and wrap it into one Vertex for each instance. Same for B. At this point, x won't be loaded because of the lazy loading.
At the end of the method, the entities will be detached (end of the first TX)
Second method
Then, the call to createEdges will start another transaction in order to create the graph edges: it will iterate over all A entity instances (by retreiving each A vertices), try to query all relationships (x) to get all Raw B instances and their wrapping Vertices to finally create a graph edge between both.
I would have expect that wrapping the overall into a transaction would have reattached the A entity to let that method query the instance  relationships (thus able to query database to load the x collection) which unfortunately doesn't.

you use data from the GraphTraversalSource gTS that you fetched in the first transaction, it probably has references to other entities that would load via lazy loading at a later time - but that has to happen within the same transaction as the initial fetch of the GraphTraversalSource, otherwise the data is invalid. With the limited information in your question it is hard to give a good advice how to get rid of this, maybe switching from a depth-first to a breadth-first algorithm (or vice versa) would help together with an appropriate split of work?

Can you please describe what 'data is invalid' means in your sentence? I'm for sure reusing entities gathered in the first method (store in the graph traversal) in the second method. But I thought data entities would be detached (end of the first method call) then reattached (because the second method call is wrapped under a transaction). Doesn't work like I described?

When you have a collection in the fetched object (usually from a 1:n or an n:m relation in the database), that collection is not filled from the database until you access it in Java. This is called "lazy loading". But that filling from the database has to happen in the same transaction, otherwise the data cannot be filled into the connection. Hibernate or other JPA implementors have their own collection implementations to provide that feature.

Sorry, but I definitely don't get why. I understand that entities are detached between the two calls, but why aren't they reattached and merged during the second?

The collections do not contain any entities yet after the first transaction ends. Please inform yourself about lazy loading, the comment section here is too small to explain it fully. Look at this SO question and its answers please: What is lazy loading in Hibernate?

I know what lazy loading is and definitely wants to use it, tried to refine what I expected in the To try to describe what this code is trying to achieve section to make it more clear. Thanks!

Where in the code do you "query all relationships x" in step 2? The sourcecode in the repository for me only shows access to the not yet loaded collections that came in form step 1, but no explicit query to the database and a manual "refill" of them - this would be necessary. I also don't see a reattaching of the loaded entities from step 1, this does not happen automatically and even if you do it manually I doubt that it would enable the lazy loading (but I didn't try that).

Does that by introspection.
Thought the reattach was done automatically due to the wrap in transaction with the right PlatformTransactionManager used
